# automatic marker generator for windows phone augmented reality

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, augmented-reality

If any one used augmented reality tool kit for windows phone [SLAR](http://slartoolkit.codeplex.com/) he will find that he need marker file (.pat) to match his images .

My questions is : is there any programmatic way to generate pattern file from image ? Or is there any web based service which I can send to it image and response with pattern? I found a lot of manual tools but i need automatic way

Answer (score 0):

The SLAR toolkit seems to be based on ARToolKit Marker technology, so you can try one of these online marker generator tools:

- [ARToolKit Marker Maker](http://roarmot.co.nz/ar/)
- [Marker's Generator (flash tarotaro)](http://flash.tarotaro.org/blog/2009/07/12/mgo2/)

(They should use the same .dat file format)